Issues adding forms to Visual Studio Project
I am working on a Windows Forms App in Visual Studio, and I created my app, but then I wanted to implement SQL Connectivity using a Local SQL Database.  I created my Database, but when I tried adding a Data Source I got a message saying that Data Sources were not available for my project type.  With a bit of reading I was able to determine that the problem was due to the fact that I had created a "Windows Forms App" instead of a "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)".  I've created a NEW project, as a "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)", and now I want to reuse the forms I have already created.  I copied the files into the folder for my new project, right-clicked in Solution Explorer and included all files in my project, but none of my forms work - I get the following errors:

If I try to open a form I get this:

I read a post on here which said that errors with adding existing forms could be fixed by excluding them from the project and then including them again, which I've tried, but it hasn't worked.
How can I fix this?  I suspect the issue is because the forms were created as part of a different project type, but I'm not sure what I need to do to the files to fix it.
Alternatively is it possible to convert my old project from "Windows Forms App" to "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" so I can use data sources?

Downgrading an application to the older .Net Framework doesn't seem like a step in the right direction.  Why do you specifically need this "Data Source"?  Is it some old control or component of some kind that's been replaced by something else?  What functionality does it provide that you specifically need here?

Probably because of implicit using is enabled in your core project, you must explicitly add missing using directives for each file in your framework project.

@David it's for a set of training materials.  I want each student to have a copy of the software with its own local SQL Database.

@shingo It looks like the using directives are present in the new project.  The only place where I can't see any using directives is in the Designer files and I know we're not supposed to modify those.

@Student228: How is that directly relevant to the problem?  What specifically is this "Data Source" and why specifically do you need that and only that?  What does it accomplish that can't otherwise be done in newer .Net versions?

That's because these files are generated by the designer, but now they are copied by you, so you are supposed to fix them.

OK, I managed to get this sorted out.  It seems I was looking in the wrong place.  I Googled "Connecting to an MDF File in .NET 6.0" (which is the version of .NET I am using) and discovered that I need to go into "Server Explorer" (NOT "Data Sources"!) and connect to my .mdf file from there.  It turns out I don't need to use an earlier version of .net.
